# The POM for org.olap4j:olap4j:jar:0.9.7.309-JS-3 is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports

I'm using **Jasper Reports** in my project and everything working fine. but when i execute mvn install this message showing for me.

> The POM for org.olap4j:olap4j:jar:0.9.7.309-JS-3 is missing, no
> dependency information available

Please not this error related with the below dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I get the same problem. That version of `jasperreports` was released in 2014. Can you use a newer version? 6.17.0 doesn't have that problem, for instance.